# Rails - Show the users that a user started following in the last month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Apologies for the question, I'm still learning rails. I'm trying to show in my html - all the users that a user has started following within the last month (i.e. recent users you've followed). I've tried two approaches-both unsuccessful. **My first try** was in my controller but the closest I got was showing users I've started following who were created in the last month. **My second try** was in my user model - but I get undefined method `call' for # Did you mean?  caller

**following.html.erb**

```
<div class="tab-content">        
<div id="fire" class="tab-pane fade">
        <% @followingurecent.each do |recentfollowing| %>
            <div class="box">
                <center>
                <%= image_tag recentfollowing.avatar, width: 85 %>
                </center>
            </div>
        <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

**Users_controller.rb**

```
def following
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    now = Time.now
    @followingurecent = @user.following.where(created_at: (now - 1.month)..Time.now)
end
```

**User.rb**

```
has_many :active_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :passive_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "followed_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower

def follow(other)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other.id)
    Notification.create(recipient: @user, actor: User.current_user, action: "Followed", notifiable: @user)
end
def unfollow(other)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other.id).destroy
end
def following?(other)
    following.include?(other)
end
def followingrecent
    now = Time.now
    self.following.where(active_relationships.where.(created_at: (now - 1.day)..Time.now))
end
```

Comment: Also you may rewrite time range as `1.month.ago..Time.now`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for the controller solution.

But the matter is that I will be looking for the relation creation time, not the user (it is user, right, I mean Follower is User model, right?).

So:

```
def following
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    # find the follower ids through the relations
    following_user_ids = @user.passive_relationships.where(created_at: (Time.now - 1.month)..Time.now).map(&:follower_id)
    # then get the followers
    @followingurecent = User.where(id: following_user_ids)
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ruby Racer - this was super helpful and worked perfectly :)