# Rails - Show the users that a user has followed who have posted a book in the last month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Apologies for the question, I'm still learning rails. I'm trying to show in my html - all the users that a user has started following who have posted a book within the last month (i.e. users you've followed that have recently posted a book). I've tried following the lessons I learned from this question [Rails - Show the users that a user started following in the last month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029961/rails-show-the-users-that-a-user-started-following-in-the-last-month) - but I'm not able to get it to work and get an error undefined method `books' for #. Thank you so much for your help.

**following.html.erb**

```
<div id="wall" class="tab-pane fade">
        <% @newpostuser.each do |newpost| %>
            <div class="box">
                <center>
                <%= image_tag newpost.avatar, width: 85 %>
                </center>
            </div>
        <% end %>
</div>
```

**Users_controller.rb**

```
def following
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 following_ids = @user.active_relationships.map(&:followed_id)
 @userfollowing = User.where(id: following_ids)
 newbook_user_ids = @userfollowing.books.where(created_at: (Time.now - 3.month)..Time.now)
 @newpostuser = User.where(id: newbook_user_ids)
end
```

**User.rb**

```
has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
has_many :active_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :passive_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "followed_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower

def follow(other)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other.id)
    Notification.create(recipient: @user, actor: User.current_user, action: "Followed", notifiable: @user)
end
def unfollow(other)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other.id).destroy
end
def following?(other)
    following.include?(other)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there is a lot you can simplify. These lines:

```
following_ids = @user.active_relationships.map(&:followed_id)
@userfollowing = User.where(id: following_ids)
```

Can just be written as:

```
@userfollowing = @user.followed
```

The next issue is that the `books` method applies to a single user (it returns the books for one user), but you are trying to apply it to a list of users. If it did work it would return a list of books not users. In your case you should be able to write:

```
@newpostusers = @userfollowing.joins(:books).where(books: { created_at: (Time.now - 3.month)..Time.now) } )
```

In general you want to try and avoid using `id`s

Comment: Marc thank you so much this was super helpful and your explanation really helped me understand the issue better. Cheers mate :)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles in a similar problem. Marc's solution worked great for a second but then stopped working giving me an error listed below

`undefined method joins' for [3,4,5]:Array Did you mean? join` 
I found a solution around it after two hours trying - there might be a more efficient way to do it but this worked awesome for me.

```
def following
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 userfollowing = @user.active_relationships.map(&:followed_id)          
 recentbook = Book.where(created_at: (Time.now - 1.month)..Time.now)
 uidsrecentbook = recentbook.map(&:user_id)
 common = (userfollowing & uidsrecentbook)
 @newpostuser = User.where(id: common)
end
```

To explain what's going on here:

First, I'm gathering the most recent books created.

Second, I'm searching using map to collect the user ids for these recent books.

Third, I'm comparing user_ids from those I'm following with the user ids of the most recent books using the power of "&"

Fourth, I create @newpostuser with my users in common. And that works perfectly :)